# Как получить ответ на запрос sql к базе без сортировки результата?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, mysqli

Делаю запрос к базе на выборку товаров по `id`, причем `id` следуют в определенном порядке.
Например, часть запроса `FROM oc_product p WHERE p.product_id IN ('574','572','573')`. 
В ответ получаю отсортированный массив. 
Мне надо получить массив с таким же порядком `id`, как и в запросе. Обработку на php полученного массива уже реализовал. Интересует можно ли сохранить порядок следования `id` именно запросом sql.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться функцией `FIELD()`, передав ей точно такую же последовательность, которую вы задаете в `IN`. Функция будет возвращать индекс значения в последовательности и по нему можно отсортировать выборку конструкцией `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  oc_product p
WHERE
  p.product_id IN ('574','572','573')
ORDER BY
  FIELD(p.product_id, '574','572','573')
```

Comment: Постарайтесь не плодить одинаковые ответы на одинаковые вопросы. В базе StackOverflow много абсолютно одинаковых вопросов ни к чему. Дубли следует закрывать.